# storing arrays within another array (3D array) in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-io, malloc

I am working on this C program, its reading in strings from a while one at a time using fgets and passing one string at a time to a function

the strings are first collected in an array (array_buffer) of size 4, and then i have another array (main_buffer) which stores array_buffer in the same order.

this should make it clear

```
main_buffer[4] = [buffer1,buffer2,buffer3,buffer4]
                    |     | 
                    |     |     .........
                    |     |     .........
                    |     V
                    |   [line1,line2,line3,line4]
                    V
                    [line1,line2,line3,line4]
                       |    |
                       |    |       ........
                       |    V       ........
                       |    [G,H,I,J,K,L]
                       V
                       [A,B,C,D,E,F](these are arrays of characters representing a string)
```

Here's my code

```
int count = 0;
int main_count = 0;

char **main_buffer[4];
char *array_buffer[4];

int reader(char *line_char){

    int lent = strlen(line_char);
    array_buffer[count] = malloc((lent + 1)*sizeof(char));      
    strcpy(array_buffer[count], line_char);     
    //this is creating buffer[4] = [line1,line2,line3,line4]
    count++;

    if (count == 4)
    {
        int row,col,line;
        //main_buffer[main_count] = malloc(sizeof(array_buffer)*sizeof(char));
        main_buffer[main_count] = array_buffer;

        if (main_count == 3)
        {
            for(col = 0; col<main_count; col++)
            {
                for(row = 0; row<count; row++)
                {
                    //printf("%s", main_buffer[col][row]);
                    for(line = 0;line < strlen(main_buffer[col][row]) ;line++)
                    {
                        printf("%c",main_buffer[col][row][line]);
                    }                   
                }
            }
            main_count = 0;
         }

    for(row = 0; row<count; row++)
    {
        free(array_buffer[row]);
    }
    count = 0;      //reverts count back to 0, so that a new array_buffer can be created
    main_count++;
    }

return 0;
}
```

My printf statement basically ends up printing the contents of array_buffer[3] 4 times instead of the contents of array_buffer[0], then array_buffer[1] then array_buffer[2] and finally array_buffer[3].

Am not able to figure out how to fix this, i know its a stale pointer issue, but then how do i solve this ? (malloc doesnt seem to work for me here) would appreciate the help.

Comment: it does enter,     count++ is before the if(count == 4), so when it hits that part count is already 4 ( but its operating as if count = 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char **main_buffer[4];
```

This isn't a 3D array. This is an array of pointers.

```
main_buffer[main_count] = array_buffer;
```

This isn't copying the contents of `array_buffer`. This is pointing one of the pointers in `main_buffer` at `array_buffer`. Every time you execute the function, you create a new alias for `array_buffer` instead of making a new, independent buffer.

Instead of repeatedly reusing `array_buffer`, you should probably be `malloc`ing a new array every time.

Comment: would you please elaborate a bit ? these are the parts I am confused about.

Comment: I don't know what specifically confuses you. The best I could do would be to give a general explanation of the semantics of assignment, pointers, and arrays in C, and if that's what you need, [The C Programming Language](http://www.barnesandnoble.com/w/c-programming-language-brian-w-kernighan/1101628765) does it much better than I could.

Comment: silly me ... i modified and tinkered around a bit, i can easily use array_buffer[4][4] and do the same thing without messing around with array of arrays ....